# Using unmanaged function in managed code giving error:Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to use the c++ dll methods in my c# project and one of the method is working fine but other one is giving the error:Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
I don't know the reason behind it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to check the type and the value of ipAddress, portNo and strResponse. For example I see that the strResponse is a String. Are you sure that this is the correct type? What is the c++ library function expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Pure guesswork of mine:

In C++ `long` is a different thing than in C#. If your C++ functions have parameters that are `long` or `unsigned long`, then in C# you should use `int` and `uint` respectively.

I guess that this is the issue, since using `C#/long` for `client port` is very strange. You don't need 64bit number for that. If that's the signature mismatch, then the third stirng parameter `response` would be damaged during marshalling and the C++ side would get an invalid pointer there.

Your current C# implementation corresponds to this C++ signature:

```
long FK_SendResponse(string addr, long port, string response);
//<->
int64 FK_SendResponse(char const* addr, int64 port, char* response)
```

I guess that you wanted to use:

```
/*C#*/ int FK_SendResponse(string addr, int port, string response);
//<->
/*C++*/ long FK_SendResponse(char const* addr, long port, char* response)
```

or

```
/*C#*/ uint FK_SendResponse(string addr, uint port, string response);
//<->
/*C++*/ unsigned long FK_SendResponse(char* addr, unsigned long port, char* response)
// (or, the same speaking with WINAPI types)
/*C++*/ HRESULT FK_SendResponse(LPSTR addr, DWORD port, LPSTR response)
```